# How can I implement single appbar icon to function differently on different tabbar?

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and I am trying to implement interface like whatsApp, on AppBar's right corner of whatsapp there is vertical 3 dots which shows list of different options **according to the tabs selected**. I want something similar. Tried looking for constructor of appBar but  was not able to find the solution how to start. Thank you in advance. Just need hint to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'example';
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  void _getCurrentTab() {
    if (_tabController.index == 0) {
      //execute code for first tab

    } else if (_tabController.index == 1) {
      //execute code for second tab

    } else {
      //execute code for third tab
    }
  }

  TabController _tabController;

  final List<Tab> tabs = [
    Tab(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.motorcycle,
      ),
    ),
    Tab(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.local_airport,
      ),
    ),
    Tab(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.local_taxi,
      ),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: tabs.length);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      initialIndex: 0,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Title Goes Here'),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
              onPressed: () => _getCurrentTab(),
            )
          ],
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: tabs,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am still confused with above code, I have single appBar with single icon, and what i want is , if 1st tab is selected, icon shows some dropdown menu with A,B . if second tab is selected, it show C,D.

Comment: im sorry misunderstood give me a second

Comment: Okay try that see if that is closer to what you want

Comment: That's what i want. Nearly close. I can implement rest. Thank you :-)